# Only one CSS media query is working

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm using CSS @media to adjust my website depending on the screen resolution
Whether i switch to a resolution with the height of 768 or 720 it will still act as if i'm my screen resolution has a height of 720px

```
.group-container{
    min-width:1210px;
    max-width:70000px;
    width:1210px;
    margin-left:2.5%;
    height:87%;
    margin-top:1%;
}

@media only screen and (max-height: 768px) {
    .group-container{
        margin-top:150px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-height: 720px) {
    .group-container{
        margin-top:3px;
        height:90%;
    }
}
```

Comment: The small `margin-top` values of the normal display and second media query appear to result in the same output, and you used a much larger top margin for the first media query. Are you expecting to see a larger top margin in normal view (≥768)?

Answer (score 0):

For the first media query you should use also a min-height set to 720px and max-height set to 768px

Comment: Still hacing the same problem, except now wether i switch to 720 or 768px it keeps showing the results as if my resolution height is 768px

Answer (score 0):

And if you try to use (max-width: ...px) instead?

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .group-container{
        margin-top:3px;
        height:90%;
    }
}
```

This way you won't rely on your height, but the width of the window it's being displayed on. example:

your resolution is 900x1600.

Resizing the height of the window wouldn't have much effect. If you where to use max-width, that way if you resize to 600x1200 for example, it would have more effect.

EDIT: The reason why I think you should use is, the height doesn't really matter when it comes to responsive design. The height might change but it will always be scrollable, so using the height will have little to no effect.

The width of the device DOES matter, the width is important when it comes to responsive design (assuming your website isn't horizontally scrollable). It would be better to create query's based on the width of the display, then to rely on height for that matter.

Comment: My website scroll horizontally scrollable, so yeah the height  does matter